# Can a spiral be represented as $F(x)+G(y)=0$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, curves, plane-curves

> Can you characterise a spiral in $\mathbb R^2$ by the equation $F(x)+G(y)=0$, where $F$ and $G$ are some continuous real-valued functions.

A spiral is any continuous parametric curve $(u(t),v(t)),t\in \mathbb R_+$ starting in the origin $(0,0)$ and such that the "angle" of $(u(t),v(t))$ relative to the origin is continuous and increasing. (I omit using polar coordinate, which makes the formulation of the angle somewhat vague. My intention is to allow for consideration of a spiral consisting of straight segments.)

Related question discussing characterisation of closed curves as $F(x)+G(y)=0$: [Closed curves of the form $F(x)+G(y)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607123/closed-curves-of-the-form-fxgy-0/4612265#4612265)

Comment: What about spirals with more arms? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612826/can-an-n-armed-spiral-be-represented-as-fxgy-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The complement of the spiral is connected, hence $F(x)+G(x)$ cannot change sign there. So wlog. $F(x)+G(x)\ge 0$ for all $x,y$.
Then for every $y\in \Bbb R$, the $x\in \Bbb R$ with $(x,y)$ on the spiral are precisely the global minima of $F$. These global minima of $F$ do not depent on $y$, of course. But then the figure consists only if straight vertical lines and is not a spiral.

Comment: Nice! Depends on the exact definition of a spiral, but I would buy this.

Comment: @HagenVonEitzen Let me ask for a clarification – what do you refer to by "the complement of the spiral"?

Comment: @Pavel, I believe he means that we can reach any point in the plane minus the locus of the spiral without crossing the spiral.

Comment: @Doug Thanks for the explanation, I got it. Really elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can still have spiraling curves in a certain sense of the word, for example with

$$x+x \sin(x)=y+y \cos(y)$$

as you can see on the following graphical representation (Desmos plotting):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this nice example! Let me ask a technical question – what program did you use to generate the graph?

Comment: Just GeoGebra...

Comment: In fact, turning to Desmos, I got a better result (new picture).

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing, Desmos is indeed very nice.