# Can an $n$-armed spiral be represented as $F(x)+G(y)=0$?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, curves, plane-curves

> Can an $n$-armed ($n\in\mathbb N$) spiral in $\mathbb R^2$ be characterised by the equation $F(x)+G(y)=0$, where $F$ and $G$ are some continuous real-valued functions.

**Definition:** An *$n$-armed spiral* is a union of $n$ curves $C_i\subset \mathbb R^2, i=1,\ldots,n$ that other than at the origin don't intersect and each $C_i$ can be represented in polar coordinates as
$$
  C_i = \Big\{
  \Big(
    r_i(t) \sin\big(\phi_i(t)\big), 
    r_i(t) \cos\big(\phi_i(t)\big)
  \Big), 
  t\in \mathbb R_+
\Big\},
$$
where both $r_i$ and $\phi_i$ are continuous increasing functions such that $r_i(0)=0$, and $\phi_i(t)\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$.

(The assumption that both $r_i$ and $\phi_i$ are increasing can be replaced by assuming that the curve $C_i$ does not intersect itself.)

I guess that if there is such an $n$-armed spiral, then it will be symmetric so that its individual arms can be obtained from each other by rotation by $2\pi/n$ about the origin.

@HagenvonEitzen [showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4612293/1134951) in a very elegant way that **for $n=1$ the answer is no**.
The argument was based on the fact that $\mathbb R^2 \setminus C_1$ forms a single connected set on which the function $F(x)+G(y)$ can not change sign. In the case of $n$ arms, $\mathbb R^2 \setminus (C_1\cup \ldots \cup C_n)$ consists of $n$ connected sets / regions. If $n$ is odd, then at least on two of the neighbouring regions the function $F(x)+G(y)$ must have the same sign, and so the @HagenvonEitzen's argument applies and it can be concluded than an even-number armed spiral cannot be represented in the desired way. What can we tell for $n$ even?

Comment: I wouldn't call this "a spiral", but it seems to me that a simple equation like $y=x+x^3$ would fit your definition of a 2-armed spiral, $\phi_2(t)=\phi_1(t)+\pi$ for all $t$. If you require that the range of $\phi_i(t)$ covers a larger interval, then we run into difficulties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing it out, I updated the definition.

Comment: Because $r_i(0)=0$ we have $F(0)+G(0)=0$. Because the angle tends to infinity, the set of solutions will (by continuity) cross the $y$-axis at infinitely many points $(0,y_i), i=0,1,2,\ldots,$. Similarly, we must intersect the $x$-axis infinitely many time, giving us points $(x_j,0), j=0,1,2,\ldots$. It follows that for all the pairs $(i,j)$ we have $F(x_i)+G(y_j)=0$. Suspicious, but I don't see a contradiction there. Must be something a bit more subtle.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Great observation! I think that using it it can be argued that $F$ has unique local extremum (I would say $F'=0$ if we could assume that $F$ is differentiable).