# Is there an algorithmic description of a bijection $\mathbb{N} \leftrightarrow \mathbb{N}^2$ with a traversal described below

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

Is there some pattern/recurrence for every column and row in distributing numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,…$ as the graphic shows?

[image: distribution of digits]

The way shown of distributing $a_1,a_2,a_3,…$ continues down and to the right for ever.

For the first row ($1,2,9,10,25,26,…$), it seems to be $n^2$ for odd, and $(n-1)^2+1$ for even $n$th element of the row

For the first column ($1,4,5,16,17,…$), it seems to be $n^2$ for even, and $(n-1)^2+1$ for odd $n$th element of the column.

Comment: When you arrive in column 1, each time, you finish a square with size $2, 4, 6, 8, 2k$  ... so, yes , 1rst column contains all number $(2k)^2$ and $(2k)^2+1$. And similar for 1rst row.

Comment: Your "traversal" reminds me of an implicit curve I gave recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4612399/305862)... but I don't see how it could be used for your issue...

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title. In partcular by replancing "digits" by "numbers" : you do not use digits (there are only 10 digits $0,1,2,\cdots 9$) but numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The following function converts $(x,y)$ coordinates, where $+x$ is right and $+y$ is down and indices start from $1$, to the $i$ of the $a_i$ at that coordinate. The function may thus be said to be the underlying pattern for the indices.

- Determine the L-shaped "shell" the coordinate lies in, where shell $n$ consists of $a_{(n-1)^2+1}$ to $a_{n^2}$ inclusive. $(x,y)$ lies in shell $s=\max(x,y)$.
- The corner of shell $n$ is $a_{n^2-n+1}$. Let $d=|x-y|$ and $i=s^2-s+1$, then

  - return $i-d$ if $s$ is odd and $x\le y$ or $s$ is even and $x\ge y$
  - return $i+d$ if $s$ is odd and $x>y$ or $s$ is even and $x<y$

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. Now, the bigger question/problem was to show that if there is some periodicity in $a_1,a_2,a_3,…$, there is also always some periodicity in every row and column.

Answer (score 1):

To identify patterns/formulas for rows or columns, we identify patterns indicated by the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$. It proves useful to also look at the sequence by following the arrows. We encode the arrows by
\begin{align*}
R&=(1,0)\qquad L=(-1,0)\\
U&=(0,1)\qquad D=(0,-1)
\end{align*}
**A pattern:**
Looking at OPs graphic we consider subsequences
\begin{align*}
s_0&=a_1a_2\cdots a_8&q_0&=RD^1L^1DR^2U^2\\
s_1&=a_9a_{10}\cdots a_{24}&q_1&=RD^3L^3DR^4U^4\\
s_2&=a_{25}a_{26}\cdots a_{48}&q_2&=RD^5L^5DR^6U^6\\
&\ \ \vdots&&\ \ \vdots\\
s_n&=a_{(2n+1)^2}\cdots a_{(2n+3)^2-1}&q_n&=RD^{2n+1}L^{2n+1}DR^{2n+2}U^{2n+2}\tag{1}\\
\end{align*}

- We see in the list above $s_n, n\geq 0$ is a subsequence starting with $a_{(2n+1)^2}$ at $(2n,0)$ following the sequence up to $a_{(2n+3)^2-1}$ with the last $U$ of $q_n$ pointing to the start $a_{(2n+3)^2}$ of the next subsequence $s_{n+1}$ at $(2n+2,0)$.
- In OPs qraphic e.g. we find with $n=1$ the element $a_{(2n+1)^2}=a_9$ at $(2n,0)=(2,0)$. We follow the sequence $s_1$ up to $a_{(2n+3)^2-1}=a_{24}$ via $RDDDLLLDRRRRUUUU=RD^3L^3DR^4U^4$ and stop before we reach $a_{25}$, the first element of the sequence $s_2$ at $(4,0)$.

> The structure of the pattern suggests to consider rows/columns at odd/even positions. In this answer we consider the column
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(2m,-n)\qquad m,n\geq 0}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> The other cases can be analysed similarly. We look at the general case (2) and consider also the special case $(2,-n)$, the column with $a_9$ at position $(2,0)$ to ease comparison.

**The sequence $q_m$:** The starting point $(2m,0)$ is easy. Here we consider the first element of the sequence $q_m$ and start with $a_{(2m+1)^2}$ at $(2m,0)$. We have in a somewhat more structural representation with sequence $q_m$, starting point, coordinate and special case ($m=1$):
\begin{align*}
&\left(q_m,\color{blue}{a_{(2m+1)^2}}\right)&\color{blue}{(2m,0)}&&\left(q_1,a_9\right)
\end{align*}

**The sequence $q_{m-1}$:**
OPs graphic clearly indicates that we can follow $q_{m-1}$ to get entries from $(2m,-1)$ downto $(2m,-2m)$. The sequnce $q_{m-1}$ is given according to (1) as
\begin{align*}
q_{m-1}=RD^{2m-1}L^{2m-1}DR^{2m}\left(U^{2m}\right)
\end{align*}
The $2m$ $U$s from $q_{m-1}$  form the part of the subsequence from $q_{m-1}$ of elements which have $x$-coordinate $2m$. We have
\begin{align*}
&\left(q_{m-1},\color{blue}{a_{(2m+1)^2-1}}\right)&\color{blue}{(2m,-1})&&\left(q_0,a_8\right)\\
&\left(q_{m-1},\color{blue}{a_{(2m+1)^2-2}}\right)&\color{blue}{(2m,-2})&&\left(q_0,a_7\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\vdots&\vdots\qquad&&\vdots\qquad\\
&\left(q_{m-1},\color{blue}{a_{(2m+1)^2-2m}}\right)&\color{blue}{(2m,-2m})&&\left(q_0,a_7\right)\\
\end{align*}

> From now on we obtain from each $q_{m+k}, k\geq 0$ two elements which have $x$-coordinate $2m$. We consider at first $q_{m}$ and consider then the general case $q_{m+k}$.

**The sequence $q_{m}$:** We look at the sequence $q_m$ and group the elements in blocks to see where we meet the elements with $x$-coordinate $2m$. We have according to (1)
\begin{align*}
q_m&=RD^{2m+1}L^{2m+1}DR^{2m+2}U^{2m+2}\\
&=\underbrace{RD^{2m+1}L}_{2m+3}\underbrace{L^{2m}DR^{2m}}_{4m+1}R^2U^{2m+2}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

- The sequence $s_m$ starts with $a_{(2m+1)^2}$ at $(2m,0)$. We follow $q_m$ one $R$ then $2m+1$ $D$s and one $L$ until we cross the vertical line at $x=2m$ again. We so have done $2m+3$ steps as shown in the first block in (3).
- Then we go $2m$ $L$s till we touch the $y$-axis, go one step down ($D$) and $2m$ steps $R$ to cross the vertical line at $x=2m$ again. Here we have done $4m+1$ more steps as indicated by the second block in (3). We so get the next two elements at $x=2m$.
  \begin{align*}
  &\left(q_{m},\color{blue}{a_{(2m+1)^2+2m+3}}\right)&\color{blue}{(2m,-2m-1})&&\left(q_1,a_{14}\right)\\
  &\left(q_{m},\color{blue}{a_{(2m+1)^2+6m+4}}\right)&\color{blue}{(2m,-2m-2})&&\left(q_1,a_{19}\right)\\
  \end{align*}

**The sequence $q_{m+k}$:** Now we are prepared for the general case $q_{m+k}, k\geq 0$. We start with $q_{k+m}$ at $(2m+2k,0)$ and have according to (1)
\begin{align*}
q_{m+k}&=RD^{2m+2k+1}L^{2m+2k+1}DR^{2m+2k+2}U^{2m+2k+2}\\
&=\underbrace{RD^{2m+2k+1}L^{2k+1}}_{2m+4k+3}\underbrace{L^{2m}DR^{2m}}_{4m+1}R^{2k+2}U^{2m+2k+2}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
and we get the two elements from $q_{m+k}$ at $(2m,-2m-2k-1)$ and $(2m,-2m-2k-2)$ from (4) as
\begin{align*}
&\left(q_{m+k},\color{blue}{a_{(2m+2k+1)^2+2m+4k+3}}\right)
&\color{blue}{(2m,-2m-2k-1})&&\left(q_{1+k},a_{(2k+3)^2+4k+6}\right)\\
&\left(q_{m+k},\color{blue}{a_{(2m+2k+1)^2+6m+4k+4}}\right)
&\color{blue}{(2m,-2m-2k-2})&&\left(q_{1+k},a_{(2k+3)^2+4k+10}\right)\\
\end{align*}

**Result:** In column $(2m,-n), m,n\geq 0$ we have according to (1) - (4) the sequence elements
\begin{align*}
&a_{(2m+1)^2-n}&\qquad &\mathrm{at}\ (2m,-n)&\qquad 0\leq n\leq 2m&\\
&a_{(2m+2k+1)^2+2m+4k+3}&\qquad &\mathrm{at}\  (2m,-2m-2k-1)&\qquad k\geq 0&\\
&a_{(2m+2k+1)^2+6m+4k+4}&\qquad &\mathrm{at}\  (2m,-2m-2k-2)&\qquad k\geq 0&\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer! With that pattern spotted, one can show that every even column (x=2m) eventually is of the form $a_i,a_j,a_{i+4t},a_{j+4t},a_{i+4t+8},a_{j+4t+8} ,a_{i+4t+16},a_{j+4t+16},…$ Something like this should be the case for every odd column and even/odd row as well, right?

Comment: @ChangLu: You're welcome! Yes, the analysis of the other cases can also be done this way.

Comment: With every even column eventually turning into some variation of the above sequence (where the difference of every second element is some fixed multiple of 4 + a linear increasing multiple of 8), how would you argue that if the original sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,…$ is periodic, every even column eventually turns periodic as well?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Inverting_the_Cantor_pairing_function) devoted to "avatars" of the so-called "Cantor pairing function" ; one of them, called "elegant pairing" discovered by [Szudzik](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf) has a strong similarity with the objective you want to achieve ; here is the very simple pseudo-code (close to the Matlab program I have written to display it) of the function $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

[image]

```
 for z=0 to n^2-1 :
    r=floor(sqrt(z));
    s=z-r^2;
    if s<r
       x=s;y=r;
    else
       x=r;y=s-r;
    endif
    place number z at position (x,y).
 end;
```

(In the wiki page, they give as well the code for the reciprocal function $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$).

I am almost convinced that this "elegant pairing" method can be adapted to generate your specific traversal.

Comment: Any comment ?....