# Could someone help me on the inverse function of $t_{x,y}=m(m+1)+(y-x)(-1)^{\operatorname{mod}(m,2)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

We are observing a point in a two-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system and that at the initial time, the point is at the origin $(0,0)$, one second later, the point moves to coordinates $(0,1)$, and another one second later, the point moves to coordinates $(1,1)$. The dataset that describes this movement is as follows:

```
instant 0: (0,0)
instant 1: (0,1)
instant 2: (1,1)
instant 3: (1,0)
instant 4: (2,0)
instant 5: (2,1)
instant 6: (2,2)
instant 7: (1,2)
instant 8: (0,2)
instant 9: (0,3)
instant 10: (1,3)
instant 11: (2,3)
instant 12: (3,3)
instant 13: (3,2)
instant 14: (3,1)
instant 15: (3,0)
instant 16: (4,0)
instant 17: (4,1)
instant 18: (4,2)
instant 19: (4,3)
instant 20: (4,4)
instant 21: (3,4)
instant 22: (2,4)
instant 23: (1,4)
instant 24: (0,4)
instant 25: (0,5)
instant 26: (1,5)
instant 27: (2,5)
instant 28: (3,5)
instant 29: (4,5)
...
```

and so on.
According to the dataset, the formula
$$t_{x,y}=m(m+1)+(y-x)(-1)^{\operatorname{mod}(m,2)},$$
where $m=\max(x,y)$,
yields the instant $t$ for a given set of coordinates $(x,y)$.

[image]

Could someone help me on the formula that determines the coordinates $(x,y)$ for a given instant $t$?
For example, given instant $10$, the formula yields the coordinates $(1,3)$.

Comment: "Moment"?  That's not what "moment" means.

Comment: It is important to say that this is a follow on of your yesterday [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4679356/305862) where my answer is based on an OEIS sequence. I haven't seen there such a formula. They propose to achieve what you want (obtaining the coordinates $(x,y)$ of a the $n$th integer in this traversal by a kind of finite-state automata.

Comment: @David G. Stork : I agree. I think there is a time reference in the word : in this case, "moment" should be replaced by "instant", assuming that a clock says "time = time +1" every time one moves forward by a unit.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you! I've updated the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible candidate would be

$$
t\mapsto (k,k)+|t-k(k+1)|\cdot v
$$
where $k=\lfloor \sqrt{t} \rfloor$, $v=f(\text{sgn}(t-k(k+1))(1-2\cdot \text{mod}(k,2)))$, and
$$
f(x)=(\frac{-1-x}{2}, \frac{-1+x}{2}).
$$

Comment: Thank you. I know $\text{mod}$ means modulo, e.g. $10\text{mod}7=3$. What does $2\text{mod}(k,2)$ mean?

Comment: @JJJohn It's just 2 times the remainder of $k$ over $2$. Updated answer to clear ambiguity.

Comment: By the way, you probably should not use this formula in practice. It's only a formula that "looks nice". In practice, just use if-else statements. For example, replace $f$ by an if-else (or hashmap) that does $1\mapsto (-1,0)$ and $-1\mapsto (0,-1)$.

Comment: I confirm your formula. Congratulations !