# A curve that can not be implicitly represented by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty F_n(a_n x + b_n y) = 0$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, curves, plane-curves

> Give an example of a simple curve $C=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: f(x,y)=0 \}$ ($f$ is an analytic function) that can not be implicitly characterized by a uniformly convergent series of functions as
> $$
>   \sum_{n=1}^\infty F_n(a_n x + b_n y) = 0, \tag{*} \label{sum}
> $$
> where $a_n,b_n \in \mathbb R$ and $F_n:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function, $n\in \mathbb N$.

The implicit characterization $F_1(x) + F_2(y) = 0$ is very restrictive, for example a spiral can not be characterized that way ([Can a spiral be represented as $F(x)+G(y)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612285/can-a-spiral-be-represented-as-fxgy-0)), and what closed curves can be written that way is discussed in the post [Closed curves of the form $F(x)+G(y)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607123/closed-curves-of-the-form-fxgy-0).

Notice that the curve $xy=0$ can not be characterized as $F_1(x) + F_2(y) = 0$ (recall that the functions have to be continuous, so $y-1/x=0$ is not of the desired form). In contrast, we can write
$$
  xy = - x^2 - y^2 +  \tfrac 1 2 (x+y)^2,
$$
so the curve can be represented as $F_1(x) + F_2(y) + F_3(x+y) = 0$. A discussion of such functions can be found here: [Can a spiral be represented implicitly as $F(x)+G(y)+H(x+y) = 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616106/can-a-spiral-be-represented-implicitly-as-fxgyhxy-0)

Although I don't see a way the curve $x^2y=0$ could be represented by $F_1(x) + F_2(y) + F_3(x+y) = 0$, it can be represented by $F_1(x) + F_2(y) + F_3(x+y) + F_4(x+2y) = 0$ for example.

Can you find a curve can not be represented by \eqref{sum}?

Answer (score 1):

Given an $n$, the set of functions $x^m y^{n-m}$ with $0 \le m \le n$ can be represented using a basis of $n+1$ functions of the form $(a_i x+ b_i y)^n$ for suitable sets of $a$ and $b$.

So any $f$ with a globally convergent Taylor series should be representable.

I think this logic can be extended to apply to all analytic $f$ -- since you could use add additional complexity to an $F_i$ to have it be zero outside of some neighborhood.

Comment: Thank you for a nice answer and welcome to Math.StackExchange. I follow the intuition of your answer. The detail that I miss being clarified is that the series of terms $(a_n x + b_n y)^N$ will be uniformly convergent (sorry that I changed notation since you posted your answer - I was mixing $i$ and $n$ originally).

Comment: I thought I had an idea for expanding this to uniform convergence, but it is incorrect. (Rather than the first N functions being enough to give you some error, it would require you to choose a different N functions at different points)