# Can a union of two disjoint simple curves be represented implicitly by $F(x)+G(y)=0$?

Tags: geometry, examples-counterexamples, curves, plane-curves

> Can you find an example of set $S$ with implicit representation $F(x)+G(y)=0$, where $F,G:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are continuous functions such that:
>
> $\ $ i) $S$ is a union of two disjoint endless simple curves $C_1, C_2$;
>
> $\ $ ii) $C_1$ is not a mirror image of $C_2$.

Graph of any continuous function $f$ can be implicitly represented by $f(x)-y=0$. Union of graphs of functions $f$ and $g$ can be implicitly represented by
$$
0 = [f(x)-y][g(x)-y] = f(x)g(x) - y^2 - [f(x)+g(x)]y,
$$
which however is separable into the form $F(x)+G(y)$ iff $f(x)+g(x)$ is constant, implying that the graphs of $f$ and $g$ are horizontal mirror of each other.

Another example is the equation
$$
  y^2 + \max\{0,1-|x+1| \} = 0,
$$
which implicitly characterizes the union of two half-lines $\{(x,0): x\leq 0\}$ and  $\{(x,0): x\geq 2\}$. However, half-lines are not endless.

Note that it can be shown that if an implicit representation $F(x)+G(y)=0$ should represent the union of curves $y=x$ and $y=x+1$, then in fact all the curves $y=x+a, a\in \mathbb Z$ are part of the solution. This can be seen from condition that if three of the points $(x_1,y_1),(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ satisfy $F(x)+G(y)=0$, then four of them do so. C.f. @DavidESpeyer comments in [Closed curves of the form $F(x)+G(y)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607123/closed-curves-of-the-form-fxgy-0/4612265#4612265)

Comment: Do you also want to rule out other horizontal/vertical lines as symmetries? Otherwise it is easy to translate the symmetry away from the axes. For example the equation
$$x^2+x=y^4+y^3+2$$ produces a curve with two connected non-intersecting unbounded components, one gotten from the other by the symmety $(x,y)\mapsto (-1-x,y)$. The right hand side is always $\ge1$, so there are no points in the strip $|x|<3/5$, where $|x|^2+|x|<1$. The term $y^3$ implies that there is no horizontal line of symmetry. However, the symmetry mentioned above is a reflection w.r.t. the line $x=-1/2$.

Comment: The quadratic formula can be used to produce a pair of solutions whose product is a constant rather than the sum like above. However, that introduces a discontinuity at $x=0$. I have in mind equations like $$x+\frac1x=3\cos y.$$ The l.h.s. is either $\ge2$ or $\le-2$, so we only get points, when $2/3\le |\cos y|$. If we want to limit the set of solutions to two components, we can modify the function of $y$ so that it stays below $2$ after a period or two, and the mirror symmetry can similarly be broken by a suitable piecewise definition of $G(y)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen (first comment) Great point, I edited the question to take into account symmetry about horizontal / vertical lines in general, not only the $x$ and $y$-axis.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen (second comment) The equation $x+1/x=3 \cos y$ generates separate closed curves. However a slightly modified equation $x+\frac{1}{x}=4+\cos y$ already generates two disjoin endless curves and they are not one mirror of the other. As you mentioned $x+1/x$ is a discontinuous function, but we can use the same idea without needing $F$ to be discontinuous. For example $x+\left(1-x\right)^{2}=2+\cos\left(y\right)$ does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comments of @JyrkiLahtonen, we can find for example the equation (I switched the role of $x$ and $y$ for the convenience of plotting the graph)
$$
  y+(1-y)^4 = cos(x),
$$
which represents two disjoint endless curves as shown in the picture:

[image]